How can I shorten this Python code from 214 bytes to under 200 bytes?
I have the following Python code, which is 214 bytes long:
G=print
B=input
A=int
H,M,N,O,I,P,Q,J=map(A,B().split())
C=[I]*H
for R in range(J):K,L=map(A,B().split());C[K]=L
while 1:D,E,F=B().split();G(['WAIT','BLOCK'][A(E)<C[A(D)]and F=='LEFT'or A(E)>C[A(D)]and F=='RIGHT'])

Is there a way to reduce its byte size to under 200 bytes without changing its functionality? Any suggestions for compression or refactoring would be greatly appreciated!

Can you do while J:J-=1;K,L=map(A,B().split());C[K]=L?

G is only used once, so inline it, and and'RIGHT'==F will save another byte.

Using B=lambda:input().split() will save you a fair number of bytes.

I truly appreciate your help, Neil. Thank you for your guidance and support

I spent a lot of time thinking about it and got stuck.

Welcome to Code Golf and nice first question! For [tag:tips] questions, it's heavily encouraged to explain what the program actually does, and in particular what inputs it has to handle, since that can make a lot of difference in how it can be golfed.

I'm voting to close this as unclear because it's a "golf this for me" question without any explanation at all of what the task is, what the requirements are, and what you've tried to far. I guess it's moot because you have an accepted answer already, but I think we should enforce some standards for this kind of question. And you can probably get further golfs and advice if you edit in more context that would help us understand what we're golfing.

197 bytes
B=lambda:input().split()
A=int
H,M,N,O,I,P,Q,J=map(A,B())
C=[I]*H
for R in range(J):K,L=map(A,B());C[K]=L
while 1:D,E,F=B();G=C[A(D)];print('BWLAOICTK'[F!=[0,'LEFT','RIGHT'][(A(E)<G)-(A(E)>G)]::2])

If while J:J-=1;K,L=map(A,B());C[K]=L works, that would save a further five bytes.
